# How do I check if Android GPS is still scanning or position is fixed? not just check if enabled

Tags: android, eclipse, gps

I know how to check if the GPS is enabled or disabled, but as the GPS is considered as disabled if the position is not fixed. I'd like to know how do I check if the GPS is scanning for a fix or if the GPS position is locked?

Code for checking if Android GPS enabled:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
          if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    }else{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GpsStatus.Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html) class for this.

```
private class MyGPSListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            switch (event) {
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    break;

                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: does Satellite status refer to scanning? (attempting to get a fix)

Comment: In your above example, it's the first item within the case statement

Comment: No it doesnt refers to scanning. You need to concentrate on `GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX`

Answer (score 0):

if you receive a location, and use GPS Provider,then it is valid and therefore fixed.
just check the timestamps to not deviate much from currenttime (location from yesterday)